# What is the default value of "position" attribute of a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering what could be the default "position" attribute of a DIV ?
Just the way a DIV has display property as BLOCK, what is the default property for position attribute ?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
position: static;
```

The default position is static for any html element if not specified explicitly.

Comment: **Check using Chrome** : `Click On the Element --> Computed --> Filter --> Show All`. Hope helps someone.

Comment: ICYMBI: a quick google search yeilds - "Static positioning is the default positioning model for elements. They are displayed in the page where they rendered `as part of normal HTML flow`"

Comment: @CotyEmbry would you like explain what does 'ICYMBI' means for non-English native speakers? I did a google search for that but found nothing.

Comment: @XiaoPeng its an acronym for In Case You Might Be Interested

Answer (score 16):

`static` is always the initial value for the CSS property `position` no matter which tag.

References:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)
- [W3C I](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position)
- [W3C II](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position)

Comment: There's a difference between the "default" value for an element, and a property's "initial value". In this case there is no browser default for `div` elements so they just take on the initial value, `static`.

Answer (score 3):

Unless it was inherited from some of its parents the default is *static*

Comment: It won't inherit from parent elements unless it is explicitly set to `position: inherit`

Answer (score 2):

Its Static. The [proof](http://jsfiddle.net/ETbCn/) of its static positioning.

The HTML:

```
<div class="position">&nbsp;<div>
    <div style="height:100px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="noposition">&nbsp;<div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.position
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
left:10px;
top:100px;
position:static;

}

div.noposition{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
left:10px;
top:100px;
}
```

It shows that Two divs with separate classes, one without any positioning and one with a static position, positions both the Div's as static.