# Div doesn't stick to the bottom in mobile devices, but does in PCs

Tags: html, css, mobile

In Chrome and Firefox, in Windows and Mac, my div appears at the bottom, as expected. However some mobile-users reported that this is not the case.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="oceanDiv" class="ocean">
  <div id="wave1" class="wave"></div>
  <div id="wave2" class="wave"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,254,234,1) 0%, rgba(255,254,234,1) 35%, #B7E8EB 100%);
  // background:#B7E8EB;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ocean { 
  height: 5%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background: #015871;
}
```

Any thoughts please?

---

<kbd>[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/ba1zy9y0/)</kbd>

where you could see this:

[image]

---

EDIT:

There was a comment says something about a div, but the user deleted it..

Comment: Now I see the same effect as my mobile users in my Mac @OriDrori..Hmm...

Comment: @OriDrori I see your point, but isn't the body height at 0 the default setting? Also it's not clear to me why I couldn't get the same effect when I minimized Chrome in Mac, giving it the size of a mobile phone, as my users..

Comment: But isn't [the position static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316834/what-is-the-default-value-of-position-attribute-of-a-div) by default? As you see my `body` doesn't have any attribute for the position.

Comment: Maybe: the div is position absolute => body doesn't have content => body is height 0px and overflow hidden => div is hidden

Comment: @Gerard but the div (`ocean`) is not hidden, it's just doesn't appear on the bottom, but rather on the middle of the screen.

Comment: Oh I see. You may want to clarify that on the question. I'll keep thinking

Comment: @Gerard I updated with a picture. However, I am wondering couldn't you reproduce that through my live demo in your mobile?

Comment: That's right, it works well on my phone (Chromium for android)

Comment: @Gerard you mean that you get the same effect as the image I posted?

Comment: No, sorry I meant that I couldn't reproduce. I just see the div at the bottom in the fiddle attached

Comment: Do you have any meta-tags defined? take a look at this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: No @Gerard, should I do? If so, considering posting an answer!

Comment: I couldn't tell because I can't reproduce. But maybe the browsers are rendering a smaller viewport for some reason. You will have to test a little with that and see what happens. Feel free to answer yourself with the solution if you manage to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `min-height: 100%` to `body`, for situations where `body` doesn't cover the whole screen. And also `height: 100%` to `html` as the parent element of `body`

Comment: Div has position: absolute and some value at bottom and left. I don't think that the body height has any effect on the div. (nor the html height). This may have something to do with viewport scaling

Comment: the way it's written in the code in the question, `body` is the parent element of that div.

Comment: But with position absolute AND some positioning attribute (like bottom) the parent relationship is broken in terms of positioning

Comment: @Johannes sorry I was just wrong. For some reason I thought that positioning attributes were relative to the viewport, not the parent. I guess I was thinking in "position: fixed"